# Response header settings is not working for the error case

Tags: go, fasthttp

**ctx.Response.Header.Set** function is not working for the error case.

Please check the below code,

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "github.com/valyala/fasthttp"

func main() {
    requestHandler := func(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
        ctx.Response.Header.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        switch string(ctx.Path()) {
        case "/foo":
            fmt.Fprintf(ctx, "Success result")
        case "/bar":
            ctx.Error("Unsupported path", fasthttp.StatusNotFound)
        }
    }
    fasthttp.ListenAndServe(":8080", requestHandler)
}
```

The /foo URL's response header is,

> Server: fasthttp Date: Mon, 16 Apr 2018 04:05:10 GMT
>
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>
> Content-Length: 14
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

But, the /bar 's response header is,

> Server: fasthttp
>
> Date: Mon, 16 Apr 2018 04:05:50 GMT
>
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>
> Content-Length: 16

Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is not applied. Is anything I missed here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with fasthttp nor do I know how a standard implementation should behave but it seems it's what the fasthttp devs [intended](https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp/blob/master/server.go#L895).

Comment: @mkopriva great find. fasthttp's document didn't mention anywhere in the document. So, I am not aware of this. Anyway thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

The method `ctx.Error` clears the headers intentionally:

```golang
// ...
// Warning: this will reset the response headers and body already set!
func (ctx *RequestCtx) Error(msg string, statusCode int) {...}
```

The solution is to use other methods:

```golang
ctx.SetContentType("text/plain")
ctx.SetStatusCode(404)
ctx.SetBodyString("Unsupported path")
```